# pkill not killing

Tags: python, process, scripts, kill

I have a Script named PirateRadio.py That I am writing a script for. 
I need to kill and reload the script. Possibly with the same PID. I thought SIGHUP was a sure thing.  when i run `#pkill -1 PirateRadio.py`

Nothing happens. Radio keeps on going. Ok, I tried `#pkill -9 PirateRadio.py`
still nothing, radio keeps right on.

```
ps aux | grep Pir
root    987 45.7 10.8 1266088 433868 ?      Sl   Mar15 2728:13 /root/PirateRadio.py
root    24924  0.0  0.0   4388   800 pts/0    S+   11:13   0:00 grep PirateRadio.py
```

so then I tried `#kill -s 1 987`
nothing happens.
`#kill -s 1 987`

then, system hang. So I dont want that, i guess. So then I use:
`#kill -s 9 987`

which kills the script well enough.
I’ve used pkill on my other desktops, What is going on here? 
where can I look to find out what pkill is or isn’t doing?

I looked in dmesg, but saw no change after running pkill
I saw no verbose option in pkill man pages..

Comment: kill -9 doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the  [pkill manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkill.1.html):

> The process name used for matching is limited to the 15 characters
>   present in the output of /proc/pid/stat.  Use the -f option to match
>   against the complete command line, /proc/pid/cmdline.

So try

```
pkill -1 -f PirateRadio.py
```

Comment: +1. You can verify with pgrep: `pgrep -l PirateRadio.py` versus `pgrep -f -l PirateRadio.py`