# I can't figure out why my python script isn't running when I use cron to run it. I've looked for hours for a solution

Tags: scripts, python, cron

So i have been trying to run my script NotifyServer.py with a cron job. It's just a simple script that sends a message to a discord server. I'm running the script on a rpi3, here's my syslog file. I don't know what to make of it as I am not that proficient at coding at all yet.

```
//www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
May  4 06:57:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
May  4 06:57:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
May  4 06:57:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 29min 40.308844s random time.
May  4 06:57:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 10min 1.139309s random time.
May  4 07:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1425]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 07:59:01 raspberrypi CRON[1454]: (pi) CMD (pkill python)
May  4 08:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[1463]: (pi) CMD (usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &)
May  4 08:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1479]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 09:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1511]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 10:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1545]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 11:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1580]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 11:59:01 raspberrypi CRON[1606]: (pi) CMD (pkill python)
May  4 12:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[1615]: (pi) CMD (usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &)
May  4 12:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1631]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 13:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1664]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 13:27:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
May  4 13:27:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
May  4 13:27:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 5h 45min 49.014375s random time.
May  4 13:27:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 7h 16min 18.482369s random time.
May  4 13:42:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
May  4 13:42:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
May  4 14:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1758]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 15:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1791]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 15:59:01 raspberrypi CRON[1817]: (pi) CMD (pkill python)
May  4 16:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[1826]: (pi) CMD (usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &)
May  4 16:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1843]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 17:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1876]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 18:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1909]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 19:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1941]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 19:59:02 raspberrypi CRON[1969]: (pi) CMD (pkill python)
May  4 20:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[1979]: (pi) CMD (usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &)
May  4 20:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1994]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 21:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2027]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 22:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2059]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 23:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2093]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  4 23:59:01 raspberrypi CRON[2120]: (pi) CMD (pkill python)
May  5 00:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[2130]: (pi) CMD (usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &)
May  5 00:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2145]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  5 01:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
May  5 01:16:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
May  5 01:16:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 6h 59min 49.631939s random time.
May  5 01:16:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 3h 30min 56.222065s random time.
May  5 01:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2225]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  5 02:03:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Session c14 of user pi.
May  5 02:11:09 raspberrypi crontab[2314]: (pi) BEGIN EDIT (pi)
May  5 02:16:58 raspberrypi crontab[2314]: (pi) END EDIT (pi)
May  5 02:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2332]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

My current `crontab -l` non-comments:

```
0 0   * * * usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &
59 3  * * * pkill python
0 4   * * * usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &
59 7  * * * pkill python
0 8   * * * usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &
59 11 * * * pkill python
0 12  * * * usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &
59 15 * * * pkill python
0 16  * * * usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &
59 19 * * * pkill python
0 20  * * * usr/bin/python home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &
59 23 * * * pkill python
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the output of `crontab -l`

Answer (score 2):

That's because the paths you provided to crontab are **incomplete**.

In Linux, each absolute path starts with `/`. Your crontab lines miss a `/` at the beginning of each path. Here's how the first line should be to work:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &
```

Also, you don't need to put 6 lines to run a command every 4 hours. You can tell cron to **run your command every 4 hours** this way:

```
0 */4 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/InvestorBot/NotifyServerV1.0.py &
```

See [this answer on cron](https://serverfault.com/a/449652/209680) or just generate your crontab configuration using [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/4_*_*_*).

Also, your second command, `pkill python`, **could be dangerous**, since could kill other instances of python running on your system completely unrelated to your command, and needed by the system.

As said [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/436448/125726), it's better to specify your script name instead:

```
pkill -1 -f NotifyServerV1.0.py
```